# how to set max connections for camel Http component

Tags: rest, apache-camel

I used servlet and camel rest dsl to define the routes.
I'm not using  xml file in my application.
how can i set max connections for http component using http component options?

Comment: You need to make an attempt at this first and if you encounter problems, you can post a question clearly explaining what you have tried and what error(s) you are getting. But it is also equally important that you do some basic research before posting your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can read something about it on this page: http://camel.apache.org/http.html.
In the sample below we set the max connection to 5 instead of the default of 2.

```
<bean id="http" class="org.apache.camel.component.http.HttpComponent">
    <property name="camelContext" ref="camel"/>
    <property name="httpConnectionManager" ref="myHttpConnectionManager"/>
</bean>

<bean id="myHttpConnectionManager" class="org.apache.commons.httpclient.MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager">
    <property name="params" ref="myHttpConnectionManagerParams"/>
</bean>

<bean id="myHttpConnectionManagerParams" class="org.apache.commons.httpclient.params.HttpConnectionManagerParams">
    <property name="defaultMaxConnectionsPerHost" value="5"/>
</bean>
```

And then we can just use it as we normally do in our routes:

```
<camelContext id="camel" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring" trace="true">
    <route>
        <from uri="direct:start"/>
        <to uri="http://www.google.com"/>
        <to uri="mock:result"/>
    </route>
</camelContext>
```

Hope it will help.